# Directory structure for storing images in a file system

Tags: dropbox, photo-management

What is the best directory structure for storing personal images in a file-system?

I have seen this structure in the past: `YYYY/MM/DD/`

But I am unhappy with it.

If I want to share a single day via DropBox or OwnCloud the directory name is too short.

I want the per-day directory name to be more meaningful.

Answer (score 4):

Don't forget you *can* have duplication without making things too hairy.

```
/year/
/year/year-month-day/
/year/year-month-day/year-month-day-hour-minute-counter.jpg
```

You're going to have, what, at most, 60-80 subdirectories at the first level, 366 at the next level (probably much fewer) and however many photos you take in a day on the next level.

Normally I'd suggest doing this with `rename` but it's fairly complicated to read from EXIF data so I'd probably suggest something like [Phatch](http://photobatch.wikidot.com/), available from the `phatch` package.

Either way, make sure you get a backup before you start, or start with a small number of photos.
Or both.